# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Function collection() cannot be called with an empty path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I'm trying to build amazon-clone.
In the payments section, I successfully makes the payment using Stripe sometimes as sometimes the clientSecret is not set(I don't know why it works and then doesn't and then works again).
After the payment is successful, I want to save the orders in firestore database.
Hence after 'then' I want to go to storing data in database.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./Payment.css";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import CheckoutProduct from "./CheckoutProduct";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";
import { useElements, useStripe, CardElement } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import CurrencyFormat from "react-currency-format";
import { getBasketTotal } from "./reducer";
import axios from "./axios";
import { db } from "./firebase";
import { collection, doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

function Payment() {
  const [{ basket, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  const [succeeded, setSucceeded] = useState(false);
  const [processing, setProcessing] = useState("");
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState();

  console.log("The total is>>>>>", Math.trunc(getBasketTotal(basket) * 100));
  //Stripe HOOKS
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();
  /////
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  //Whenever basket changes, it will make this request and it will update the special stripe secret which allows us to charge the customer the correct amount.
  useEffect(() => {
    //generate the special stripe client secret that allows us to charge the customer
    const getClientSecret = async () => {
      const response = await axios({
        method: "post",
        //Stripe expects the total in a currencies subunits, hence * 100
        url: `/payments/create?total=${Math.trunc(
          getBasketTotal(basket) * 100
        )}`,
      });

      setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret);
    };

    getClientSecret();
  }, basket);
  ////////

  console.log("The Secret is>>>", clientSecret);
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    //do all fancy stripe stuff...
    event.preventDefault(); //stops from refreshing
    setProcessing(true); //helps in stopping user to click Buy button multiple time while processing. basically disbales the button after one use.
    const payload = await stripe
      .confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
        payment_method: {
          card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
        },
      })
      .then(({ paymentIntent }) => {
        //paymentIntent = payment confirmation
        console.log("I was called and didn't do shit", collection("users"))
        //NoSQL Type retrieval of data
        const paymentRef = doc(
          db,
          collection("users"),
          user.uid,
          collection("orders"),
          paymentIntent.id
        );
        
        setDoc(paymentRef, {
          basket: basket,
          amount: paymentIntent.amount,
          created: paymentIntent.created,
        });
        setSucceeded(true);
        setError(null);
        setProcessing(false);

        // dispatch({
        //   type: "EMPTY_BASKET",
        // });
        //Move to orders page, not at the payment page again. Duh...
        navigate("/orders");
      });
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    //Listen for changes in Card Element
    //and display any error as the customer types their card details
    setDisabled(event.empty);
    setError(event.error ? event.error.message : "");
  };
  return (
    <div className="payment">
      <div className="payment__container">
        <h1>
          Checkout (<Link to="/checkout">{basket.length} items</Link>)
        </h1>
        {/* Payment Section - Delivery Address */}
        <div className="payment__section">
          <div className="payment__title">
            <h3>Delivery Address</h3>
            <div className="payment__address">
              <p>{user?.email}</p>
              <p>123, Chaurangi Lane</p>
              <p>New Delhi, India</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        {/* Payment Section - Reviewing Items */}
        <div className="payment__section">
          <div className="payment__title">
            <h3>Review Items and Delivery</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="payment__items">
            {basket.map((item) => (
              <CheckoutProduct
                id={item.id}
                title={item.title}
                image={item.image}
                price={item.price}
                rating={item.rating}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>

        {/* Payment Section - Payment Method */}
        <div className="payment__section">
          <div className="payment__title">
            <h3>Payment Method</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="payment__details">
            {/* Stripe Magic Happens here */}
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <CardElement onChange={handleChange} />
              <div className="payment__priceContainer">
                <CurrencyFormat
                  renderText={(value) => (
                    <>
                      <h3>Order Total: ${value}</h3>
                    </>
                  )}
                  decimalScale={2}
                  value={getBasketTotal(basket)}
                  displayType={"text"}
                  thousandSeparator={true}
                  prefic={"$"}
                />

                <button disabled={processing || disabled || succeeded}>
                  <span>{processing ? <p>Processing</p> : "Buy Now"}</span>
                </button>
              </div>

              {/* ERRORS */}
              {error && <div>{error}</div>}
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Payment;
```

Firebase.js

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "Hidden from public",
  authDomain: "Hidden",
  projectId: "Hidden",
  storageBucket: "Hidden",
  messagingSenderId: "Hidden",
  appId: "Hidden",
  measurementId: "Hidden"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export default app;
```

In functions folder I have index.js

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const stripe = require("stripe")('my_key');

//API

// - App config
const app = express();
// - Middlewares
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
app.use(express.json());
// - API routes

app.get("/", (request, response) => response.status(200).send("hello world"));

app.post("/payments/create", async (request, response) => {
  const total = request.query.total;
  console.log(
    "Payment Request Received BOOM!! BOOM!! for this amount >>> ",
    total
  );
  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: total, //subunits of the currency
    currency: "inr",
  });
  // - 201 => OK - Created
  response.status(201).send({
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
  });
});
// - Listen command
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

No when I go to payment and put test card as 42424242..., and click 'Buy Now'.The button text changes to 'Processing' and if there is a clientSecret set it does the payment but it shows incomplete sometimes and does the payment. The page never proceeds to /orders page.
Also it doesn't goto .then function and console.log("I was called") and never saves data in the firestore. Instead gives this error in browser console ->

> 

```
The total is - 383106
Payment.js:47 The Secret is: pi_3LmGzhAkzUGZaOjE0j5CQGDX_secret_mEUL5ROsMK4JP0SNCjmMCh34Z
Payment.js:95 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Function collection() cannot be called with an empty path.

await (async) callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430
```

ALSO why does my stripe payments get successfull after so many attempts in backside.  -> [A snap of stripe payments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmXnO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `collection()` takes a Firestore instance as first parameter but you are passing the collection name itself. Also, you don't have to use `collection()` within the `doc()` function to create a `DocumentReference` for nested document. Try:

```
const paymentRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid, "orders", paymentIntent.id);
```

The `setDoc()` returns a Promise so try waiting for it to resolve before redirecting user to any other route as shown below:

```
const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
  payment_method: {
    card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
  },
}).then(async ({ paymentIntent }) => {
  // ^^ async function
  const paymentRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid, "orders", paymentIntent.id);

  // await here
  await setDoc(paymentRef, {
    basket: basket,
    amount: paymentIntent.amount,
    created: paymentIntent.created,
  });

  setSucceeded(true);
  setError(null);
  setProcessing(false);
  navigate("/orders");
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That did it. I'm new to this. Btw why does useEffect doesn't give me clientSecret when on load of Payment.js component. It runs only when I 'delete some item'/'make changes' from/in basket. Sometimes it does run on load and sometimes it doesn't.